# How to use like operator with %?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a search bar and I am having a hard time constructing the correct query for that. Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(
    "Select * from tbl_customer where customer_name like '%''"+ textBox1.Text +"''%' ",
    MySqlConnection);
```

Comment: Just remove a couple of ', so it reads: `LIKE '%" + ... + "%'"`

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_customer where customer_name like @search_value", MySqlConnection);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_value","%" + textBox1.Text + "%");
```

Comment: This actually prevents SQL injection and is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding too many 's.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(
    "Select * from tbl_customer where customer_name like '%"+ textBox1.Text +"%' ",
    MySqlConnection);
```

Note that I have removed the extra 's after the first % and before the last %.

However, you should be careful about SQL injection and use parameters instead of directly adding control values into your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(
    "Select * from table-name where column-name like '%"+ textboxid.Text +"%' ",
    MySqlConnection);
```

If u making a sample program then ok it will work ,but if you are looking for a professional use software or website then don't go with this method . Check sql injection because here you are directly adding the  control values in query